# Problem with relationship between shunt resistance and grain boundaries in a solar cell

Tags: material-science, solar-energy, photovoltaics, electronics, semiconductor

[Here is the correct answer from another stack website](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/570917/288858).

The higher shunt resistance means that higher the
polycrystalline lattice irregularity and many grain boundaries. This
means higher current resistance and thus less current output, so
efficiency of solar cell decreases. However, in the circuit model of a
solar cell, a shunt resistor is connected in parallel to the diode and
they say that it must have infinite resistance for the highest current
output cuz it is in parallel. However infinite grain boundary
irregularity means that there is infinite resistance to the whole
current in the solar cell so no current flowing is produced.

There is a conflict here.

[image]

https://www.scirp.org/html/7-6401007/fe85a7b6-645d-4341-8f35-dde69e519017.jpg

[image]

[image]

[image]

Warning: This is a crosspost, although noone answered my question, here are the links:

- [My cross-post on Electronics SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/570894/why-does-the-value-of-shunt-resistor-need-to-be-very-high-for-solar-cells-great)
- [My cross-post on Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/645123/why-does-the-value-of-shunt-resistor-need-to-be-very-high-for-solar-cells-great)

Comment: A duplicate: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/570894/152903

Comment: And here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/645123

Comment: noone answers to my question I am aware that they are duplicates @Solar Mike

Comment: Simple, warn people you are cross-posting so they don’t waste their effort.

Comment: I did. @Solar Mike

Comment: Well, you have now but not originally...

Comment: do you have any solution to my question? @Solar Mike

Comment: Here is the correct answer from other stack website: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/570917/288858

Comment: Been there, read it and voted. and voted before you accepted...

Comment: Nice to see you got the answer eventually! I know this is a long-shot, but since you talked about grain boundaries I wonder if you have any idea how to answer [this question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2356/5)?  It's been one of our longest-lasting unanswered questions and I'd really like to clean up the unanswered queue!